# XHR, $.ajax, как прервать success callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть такая страничка со вкладками, открываешь каждую - она грузится секунд за 10, причем сам запрос может отработать довольно быстро, а вот именно success-callback - несколько сек, и юзер за это время может нажать другую вкладку, и получается путаница.

Так вот, как остановить старый success-callback? Кроме вставить if (stopped) return через какую строчку?

Comment: `юзер за это время может нажать другую вкладку,и получается путаница.` - какая путаница? и причем тут какая-то другая вкладка? лучше написать подробно что пытаетесь сделать.. А то сейчас выглядит попыткой написать костыль

Comment: @АлексейШиманский достаточно подробно все изложено. вкладки не браузера, а на странице. он открывает первую вкладку, она начинает грузиться, тут он открывает вторую, а тем временем прогружается первая и появляется, но еще через какой-то интервал вместо нее появляется вторая.

Comment: Видишь, если бы было "подробно" все изложено, то уже бы не возникло дополнение что `вкладки не браузера, а на странице` оказывается. И опять же возникают вопросы:  что это за вкладки? что туда грузится? почему нужно на другой вкладке что-то останавливать? Потому что наверняка можно посоветовать что-то адекватное вместо желаемого на данный момент поведения

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Невнимательно читал, написано же "страничка со вкладками". Вкладки как вкладки: на странице есть 1 div content, в него и грузится содержимое при нажатии на ту или иную вкладку. Что грузится - Гимн Третьего Рейха в первую вкладку, а фашистской Италии - во вторую. Почему останавливать - см. выше.